# Declared package doesn't match the expected package inet.example.nclient error in omnet 4.0p1 in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: omnet++, opc-ua

I have developed a code with client and server, using the following `NED` file:

```
import inet.examples.ethernet.lans.ethernetline;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.FlatNetworkConfigurator;
import inet.nodes.inet.Router;
import inet.nodes.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.world.ChannelInstaller;
import inet.world.NAMTrace;
import ned.DatarateChannel;

network NClients
{
parameters:
    int n;

types:
    channel fiberline extends DatarateChannel
    {
        delay = 1us;
        datarate = 2Mbps;
    }
    channel ethernetline extends DatarateChannel
    {
        //      delay = exponential(0.1us);
        datarate = 2Mbps;
    }

submodules:
    channelInstaller: ChannelInstaller {
        parameters:
            channelClass = "ThruputMeteringChannel";
            channelAttrs = "format=u";
            @display("p=98,50");
    }
    configurator: FlatNetworkConfigurator {
        parameters:
            @display("p=208,50");
    }
    nam: NAMTrace {
        parameters:
            @display("p=298,49");
    }
    r1: Router {
        parameters:
            @display("p=186,250");
    }
    r2: Router {
        parameters:
            @display("p=304,220");
    }
    r3: Router {
        parameters:
            @display("p=433,250");
    }
    cli[n]: StandardHost {
        parameters:
            @display("i=device/laptop");
    }
    srv: StandardHost {
        parameters:
            @display("p=544,194;i=device/server_l");
    }

connections:
    for i=0..n-1 {
        cli[i].pppg++ <--> ethernetline <--> r1.pppg++;
    }

    r1.pppg++ <--> ethernetline <--> r2.pppg++;
    r2.pppg++ <--> ethernetline <--> r3.pppg++;
    r3.pppg++ <--> ethernetline <--> srv.pppg++;
}
```

However, there are 6 errors in my project:

> declared package doesn't match the expected package inet.example.nclient

In every `.ned` file there is the same kind of error in 1st line. (I couldn't post my images as it saying you need 10 reputation to post images.)

Please help

with best regard

Saurabh

Comment: Thanks for editing...now it looks better

Comment: The error is coming on the 1st line and it saying multiple marker at this line..... - declared package doesn't match the expected package inet.example.nclient... -11 changed lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the directory, where your `NED` files are located, edit or add file `package.ned` with the following content:

```
package test1;
```

Then at the beginning of every `NED` file add the following line (as 1st line):

```
package test1;
```

Moreover, in `omnetpp.ini` one should select a proper network, i.e.:

```
[General]
network = test1.NClients
```

Instead of `test1` one can use any other name. I suggest using the name of folder with your project.
Reference: [OMNeT++ Manual, 3.14 Packages](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:packages).

Comment: yes i have created a new package.ned file .... by right clicking the folder---new ned file....but where to write package test1   ?

Comment: But when i am now running the program it is saying error in module opc_testCliApp, error evaluating parameter 'sessionconfig': error reading 'conf/conf'_o : xml input is not supported: this copy of NEDXML was complied without an XML parser (libXML or Expat)..