# Declared package does not match expected package in OMNET++

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to simualte M\M\1 Queuing Model using OMNET++ on my Mac M1.
The name of the project is "MM1QueueModel" while the same for .ned and .cc are "MM1Queue.ned" and "MM1Queue.cc" respectively.
In the "MM1Queue.ned" file, I am using the package as:

```
package MM1QueueModel;
```

but this is giving an error "Declared package does not match expected package in OMNET++"
The solution described in [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316896/declared-package-doesnt-match-the-expected-package-inet-example-nclient-error-i) is not working for me. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Packages Overview](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:packages-overview) and check whether your directories meet that requirement:

> The package name that follows from the directory name and the declared package must match; it is an error if they don't.